# Unable to open database file when the App is installed in Program Files in Windows 7

Tags: php, sqlite, windows-7

I have a PHP Desktop application. This app is successfully installed and tested in Windows XP, however, there is a problem when it is installed in Windos 7 under c:\Program Files\myApp folder, the database file couldn't be open and results in the error message:

> SQLite3::query: Unable to open database file in C:\Program
>   Files\myApp\www\checkLogin.php

Note:- My database is in the same
location as the PHP script,i.e, www\myDatabase.db .

The code I used to connect to the database is:-

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3 
 {
    function __construct() 
    {
      $this->open('myDatabase.db');
    }
 }
 $db = new MyDB();

 if(!$db) 
 {
   echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
 }
```

If I reinstall the app in some other location, say, C:\myApp, there is no problem and the app runs successfully.

(Personally I think it is more of a ***security issue*** of the Operating System.)

So, what causes the database file to be debarred from opening in the Program Files folder? And what to do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually advised to install directly to your root drive example `C:\myApp` this is because of windows `User Account Control` setting prevents some certain functionality to protect your system.

Changing the UAC setting's may allow your program to run from any other directory but exposes your computer to other risks from malicious programs.

Comment: well it is. But, when we install other commercial apps,they can be run from the Program Files folder in Windows. So from this point of view, how do the apps companies manage to run them from the same folder,i.e.Program Files?

Comment: Your question is leaving the boundaries of stack overflow it is more of a [superuser question](https://superuser.com) but to explain php applications are service based application meaning they run in the background on a server or sometimes create there own server windows wont give permission to any service that may compromise the OS which is what can happen if your not careful with service based apps. So you run the app at your own risk but such security futures were not available in older OS hence it works in windows XP but not Win7.